# Is it possible to flip a div with css3 on an android

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-webkit

On IOS or chrome a div will flip if i call a keyframe like this one:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); }
```

}

But on an android phone the div rotate 90 degrees. Is there a fix to flip the div also on an android device?

Comment: The native android browser can't handle 3d i guess. You have no other workaround then getting another browser. See [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=3d)

Comment: Im doing the same, and also cant get it working on android phone.

Comment: 'cept those aren't 3D transitions. Those are 2D. The version of Webkit on the phone you're using must be chopped down in some way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 animation does not work on Android 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271190/css3-animation-does-not-work-on-android-4-2)