# CSS3 animation does not work on Android 4.2

Tags: android, css, animation, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing an app using Worklight where I need to put a small animated image using CSS. In tests on Android devices with version 4.4 works perfectly, I performed some tests on devices with Android 4.2 and 4.1 and this same animation does not work. IPhone 5 is working perfectly.

My code is:

```
<html>

    <style type="text/css">

        .image-arrow {
          content: url("http://i104.photobucket.com/albums/m163/bl82/arrowup-green.png");
          /* content: url("hand.png"); */
          /* display: inline-block; */
          width: 100px;
          text-align: center;
          margin: auto;
          overflow: visible;  
          /* position: absolute; */
        }

        .element-animation{
          -webkit-animation: 4.0s ease-in-out;
          -webkit-animation-name: animationFramesWebKit;
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
          -webkit-transform-origin: 60% 100%;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes animationFramesWebKit {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg);
          }
          8% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg);
          }
          18% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(-25deg) ;
          }
          25% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(25deg) ;
          }
          32% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(-25deg) ;
          }
          41% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(25deg) ;
          }
          50% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(-25deg) ;
          }
          61% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(25deg) ;
          }
          70% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(-25deg) ;
          }
          85% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(25deg) ;
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg);
          }
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="top-body image-arrow element-animation"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I create a file with this HTML and open on Android 4.2 does not work, but on Android 4.4 works perfectly.
Any idea what Android 4.2 and lower does not support and if there is any alternative for this?

Comment: What browser are you using to test this on your phone?

Comment: I saved this code in a html file and open with HTML Viewer app, but does not work generating the hybrid application using Worklight.

Comment: Which device running android 4.2 did you try to test your app on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini GT-I9192 running Android 4.2 and Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 running Android 4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Past versions of Webkit has trouble rendering animation for pseudo elements, such as `:after` and `:before`. In your case, the `.image-arrow` class has the `content:` property which is generally reserved for use in pseudo elements only. I suggest you replace it with `background-image`, for eg:

```
.image-arrow {
   background-image: url("http://i104.photobucket.com/albums/m163/bl82/arrowup-green.png");
   /* content: url("hand.png"); */
   /* display: inline-block; */
   width: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   overflow: visible;  
   /* position: absolute; */
}
```

This problem (now solved) with Webkit is well documented: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632

Chrome PC implemented this after version 26, iOS after 6.1, and Android on 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Change .image-arrow to below:

```
   .image-arrow {
      background-image: url("http://i104.photobucket.com/albums/m163/bl82/arrowup-green.png");
      background-size: 100px 100px;
      /* content: url("hand.png"); */
      /* display: inline-block; */
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: visible;  
      /* position: absolute; */
    }
```

In many version of WebView Android, several properties of css3 not working correctly.