# Css keyframe not work on cordova android (< 4.4)

Tags: android, css, cordova

```
@-webkit-keyframes headerFade
  0%
    opacity: 0
  50%
    opacity: 1
  99%
    opacity: 0
@keyframes headerFade
  0%
    opacity: 0
  50%
    opacity: 1
  99%
    opacity: 0

.header
  width: 100px
  height: 100px
  background: #ccc
  position: relative

.header.ani:before
  content: ' '
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  background-color: #000000
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
  -webkit-animation: headerFade 1s linear infinite
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards
  animation: headerFade 1s linear infinite
```

[codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/regFI)

It's works fine on chrome, but no animate(only 0 and 1) on cordova android app(<4.4). I find same issue on transform(background-image), it's only work on 4.4 device, but [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) says it's supported by android browser > 4.0. Did I have something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Past versions of Webkit has trouble rendering animation for pseudo elements, such as :after and :before. In your case, the .image-arrow class has the content: property which is generally reserved for use in pseudo elements only. I suggest you replace it with background-image, for eg:

```
e.header.ani /*:before*/
  /*content: ' '*/
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  background-color: #000000
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
  -webkit-animation: headerFade 1s linear infinite
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards
  animation: headerFade 1s linear infinite
```

Comment: On android < 4.4 `transform(background-image)` skip animation too.

Comment: I don't think so. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271190/css3-animation-does-not-work-on-android-4-2/25277139#25277139